# The sum of the coefficients of $P(x)$ of 4th degree given that $P(x)\equiv x-1 \pmod{2x^2+4}\equiv x-1 \pmod{x^2-x-2}\equiv 141 \pmod{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

Let there be a polynomial $P(x)$ of 4th degree. The remainder of $P(x)$ divided by both $2x^2+4$ and $x^2-x-2$ is equal to $x-1$. So:

$$P(x)\equiv x-1 \pmod{2x^2+4}\equiv x-1 \pmod{x^2-x-2}$$

Given that $P(x)\equiv 141 \pmod{x+2}$, I'm asked to calculate the sum of the coefficients of $P(x)$.

I don't have any idea how I should go about solving the question, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**:$$P\left( x \right) =a\left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }+4 \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }-x-2 \right) +x-1\\ P(x)\equiv 141{ \quad \left( mod\quad x+2 \right) \Rightarrow  }P\left( -2 \right) =141\\ P\left( -2 \right) =48a-3=141\\ 48a=144\\ a=3\\ P\left( x \right) =3\left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }+4 \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }-x-2 \right) +x-1\\ $$
**Hint 2**

$P(1)=$sum of the coefficients of $P(x)$.

Comment: So the open form of the polynomial is $P(x)=9x^4-9x^3-17x-37$. Well, its remainder is indeed $x-1$ when divided by both $2x^2+4$ and $x^2-x-2$. However, when divided by $x+2$, it gives the remainder 213 instead of 141.  Though I don't know why your solution doesn't hold, it seemed correct.

Comment: On a second note, why $P(x)\equiv 141{ \quad \left( mod\quad x+2 \right) \Rightarrow  }P\left( -2 \right) =141$? Wouldn't $x=-2$ result in $mod$ $0$ which is undefined. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Glycerius,it was a typo,should be $3$ insteed of $4.5$

Comment: @Glycerius,for your second question it is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem,think about $P\left( x \right) =\left( x+2 \right) Q\left( x \right) +141$